# Implementing a while loop inside a try-catch method in Java

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

So basically what I'm trying to do with my code is look through a payroll.txt file looking like this:

```
31718 PHILLIP LENNOX 55.0 20.00
11528 NANCY TROOPER 40.0 10.45
16783 JOHN CONNAUGHT 30.5 10.00
10538 PETER DUNCAN 45.0 10.75
21O15 JAMES HAROLD 32.0 10.50
61326 HARRY KUHN 25.0 12.30
82465 MICHELLE BENOIT 50.0 18.50
31816 DANIELLE RAYMOND 35.5 15.25
73745 JACK O'TOOLE 28.0 11.50
```

And pick up InputMismatchExceptions or a double that's lower than 10.35 (As seen in my code below) and print out that whole line in another file called payrollError.txt. The problem I'm getting here is basically this prints to my payrollError.txt file:

```
31718 PHILLIP LENNOX 55.0 20.0
11528 NANCY TROOPER 40.0 10.45
10538 PETER DUNCAN 45.0 10.75
0 null null 0.0 0.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0
(These lines go on infinitely)
```

And I can't seem to figure out the problem. I've tried various different methods but get no out prints at all, or this massive infinite printout.

```
  import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Employee> ArrEmployee = new ArrayList<>(); //  array for employee objects

        try (PrintWriter txtOut = new PrintWriter("payrollError.txt")) {

            Scanner txtIn = new Scanner(new File("payroll.txt")); 

            while (txtIn.hasNext()) { // looping through the payroll.txt file and creating Employee objects from its data
                 long EmployeeNumber = 0;
                 String EmployeeName = null;
                 String LastName = null;
                 double HoursWorked = 0;
                 double HourlyWage = 0;

                 try{
                      EmployeeNumber = txtIn.nextLong();
                      EmployeeName = txtIn.next();
                      LastName = txtIn.next();
                      HoursWorked = txtIn.nextDouble();
                      HourlyWage = txtIn.nextDouble();

                        if (HourlyWage > 10.35){ 
                            throw new MinimumWageException(); // throws exception if the hourly wage is less than 10.35$
                                }

                        else
                            ArrEmployee.add(new Employee(EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName,LastName,HoursWorked,HourlyWage)); // creates Employee objects according to the input payroll.txt
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException n) { // catching long,strings and doubles in the payroll.txt that aren't valid
                     txtOut.println(EmployeeNumber + " " + EmployeeName + " " + LastName + " " + HoursWorked + " " + HourlyWage);
                     txtIn.hasNext();

                     }
                 catch (MinimumWageException z){
                     txtOut.println(EmployeeNumber + " " + EmployeeName + " " + LastName + " " + HoursWorked + " " + HourlyWage);
                     txtIn.hasNext();
                 }
                      }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File payroll.txt was not found.");

            }

    }
```

}

Comment: Better question: why are you using exceptions for normal program flow? Instead of throwing the exceptions try just putitng the `MinimumWageException` handling code inside the `if`.

Comment: @CompuChip Because If there's an error inside the payroll.txt, it prints out the line with the error inside of a payrollError.txt file. Also the MinimumWageException does the same thing, except it checks for the last double of the line, see if it's under 10.35 and if it is, prints it out to the payrollError.txt

Comment: @X1XX printing out lines that are invalid to an error text file has nothing to do with throwing exceptions.  You could just print to the file directly within the if block instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: It's actually throwing when the wage is _over_ 10.35. But my point is, exceptions should be used for exceptional situations, like reading a string where you are expecting a double. Since the purpose of this function seems to be exactly to validate the payroll file, you do not need an exception here, you can just go: `if( minimumWage > 10.35 ) { txtOut.println("..."); } else { employees.add(new Employee( ... )); }`.
Also, the call to `txtIn.hasNext()` in the `catch`es seems to be obsolete as you are not using the result.

Comment: @CompuChip The thing is, my assignment specifically says I have to use try-catch with exceptions! I wouldn't if it wasn't mandatory :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here. One already pointed out is that you have `(HourlyWage > 10.35)` instead of `(HourlyWage < 10.35)`. The main problem is that after you encounter the input mismatched caused by having the letter "O" instead of the number `0` in `21O15`, the scanner leaves the token in the stream. That's why you get into the infinite loop. You keep reading the bad input over and over. Of course none of the variables like `EmployeeName` etc. get assigned a value, which is why you see the 0's and nulls being printed from the catch block.

To fix the infinite loop, you need to eat the rest of the line before going back to the top of the loop. Note the `txtIn.nextLine()` instead of the `txtIn.hasNext()` you had before. (I'm not sure why you have `txtIn.hasNext()` in your catch blocks.)

```
catch (InputMismatchException n) { // catching long,strings and doubles in the payroll.txt that aren't valid
    txtOut.println("IME: " + EmployeeNumber + " " + EmployeeName + " " + LastName + " " + HoursWorked + " " + HourlyWage);
    txtIn.nextLine()
}
```

**EDIT**
To work around the problem of not having read in the values you're trying to print in the catch block, you can print the ones that were successfully read followed by the rest of the line retrieved by `nextLine()`:

```
            catch (InputMismatchException n) { // catching long,strings and doubles in the payroll.txt that aren't valid
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(EmployeeNumber == 0 ? "" : (EmployeeNumber + " "));
                sb.append(EmployeeName == null ? "" : (EmployeeName + " "));
                sb.append(LastName == null ? "" : (LastName + " "));
                sb.append(HoursWorked == 0.0 ? "" : (HoursWorked + " "));
                sb.append(HourlyWage == 0.0 ? "" : (HourlyWage + " "));
                sb.append(txtIn.nextLine());
                txtOut.println(sb.toString());
            }
```

It's not perfect because 0.0 could be a legal value for hours worked, e.g., but maybe it's good enough for your purposes. In any case, one problem at a time :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! But now it prints this out `16783 JOHN CONNAUGHT 30.5 10.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0
52726 MITCHELL HACKETT 0.0 0.0
0 null null 0.0 0.0
22310 CLAUDIA O'HARE 30.5 9.8` and doesn't print the doubles at the end of Mitchell Hackett for example, and still prints out some nulls..

Comment: I've narrowed it down the problem is that when it's the long at the beginning of the line that's mismatch it prints out as 0 null null 0.0 0.0... Any idea?

Comment: Yes, the ones that cause the `MinimumWageException` should print fine, but the ones that cause `InputMismatchException` are a problem because they jump into the catch block without reading the values into the variables that are getting printed. Whatever variables haven't yet been read before the exception will have their initial values (0.0 for the numeric variables, `null` for the Strings).

Comment: Any idea how I could remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the documentation for the Scanner class. It says that

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method.

That means, that instead of calling `hasNext()` in the catch block, you should call `skip()`